# How to add label to asp full calendar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>ASP.NET FullCalendar</title>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="cal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="calendar">
</div>
<div runat="server" id="jsonDiv" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdClient" runat="server" />
</form>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/calendarscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to add asp label on each days of the above calendar? 
A label where I can display text from code behind.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a normal asp:calendar as shown below and and display the label from code behind.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cal2" runat="server" Width="100%" DayField="Date" 
 OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" BackColor="Orange" NextMonthText="Next" 
 PrevMonthText="Prev" OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged" >
<DayStyle CssClass="days" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Name="Arial" Height="100px"   BackColor="lightYellow"  />
<TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightBlue"  />
<OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightGray" ForeColor="DarkGray"/>
</asp:Calendar>
```

Now on the day render event you can use LiteralControl to show label.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    e.Cell.Font.Size = 9;
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Your label</p>"));
}
```